# PyQt5: How to get the MainWindow layout?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

So when I try to add a layout to the MainWindow
`self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.MainWindow)`
I get this error:
`QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QMainWindow "MainWindow", which already has a layout`

How do I get the default layout? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

A `QMainWindow` layout is quite custom and consists of a central widget and other dynamic parts (e.g. menu, statusbar, toolbars, dock areas). It does not make much sense replacing it as then you would simply start with a plain `QWidget` instead.

The layout you typically want to edit on a `QMainWindow` is the layout of its `centralWidget`. You can [get](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget)/[set](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) that one and operate on it accordingly (including layout).

Comment: Okay thank you but I have another question.
I've tried setting up a central widget, and I want to place some widget in the center of it.
I did that by using 
`self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.CentralWidget)`
`self.mainLayout.addWidget(myWidget, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)`
But it takes the whole layout cause it's the only widget there.
I want to resize it so it actually looks like it's in the center, not taking the whole layout.

Comment: @Leo If you want that kind of result, you'll need to add spacings before and after adding the widget to the layout. I'd suggest you to read the docs about [QMainWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details) and [layout management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), especially those about the main layout managers (V/HBoxLayout and GridLayout).

Answer (score 0):

As answered by other(s), `QMainWindow` has its own layout.

But if at all you want to add a fixed size widget to the main windows's central widget, probably you can use, `setFixedSize` method of the widget, that you want to add to central widget.

example:

```
centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(centralWidget)

#Set the fixed size
anotherWidgetOne.setFixedSize(20,20)

#Add other widgets to the central widget
layout.addWidget(self.anotherWidgetOne)

#Set the central widget
self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
```